# Make right click ---> Paste work in input style=text and button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, button

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#links').change(function() {
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);
    })
});
```

But when the first thing I do when I load the page is rightclick paste and hit the button, the button is disabled.. I need to click 'outside' the text field before I click the button if I want it to work.. is there any way round this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change the event to [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) instead of `change`, if you do not want it fired every time the users types though you could also change it to [`paste`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/paste), which is fired when something is pasted from clipboard

Answer (score 0):

The [`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event is a bit misleading as it waits until focus is lost until it actually triggers the function :

> For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired
>   immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but **for
>   the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses
>   focus.**

If you want to trigger it immediately, then you may want to consider binding to an event that does trigger immediately such as detecting input via the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event :

```
// The input event should handle any types of input that comes in (including paste)
$('#links').on('input', function(){
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);
});
```

**Example**

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Copy Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input id='links' />
  <input id='submit' type='submit' />

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
      $('#links').on('input', function() {
        console.log('Input detected');
        $('#submit').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've updated it to use different events namely `input` and `propertychange`, which should handle both scenarios (keypress events and paste).

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! WORKS JUST AS I WANTED TO! :))))

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a space-delimited list of events using `on`, which will listen for any of the events related to the action that you're looking for:

```
$('#links').on("change keyup paste", function() {
  $('#submit').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);
});
```